# How do you tell Karma to keep browser window open if tests fail?

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm currently trying to implement jasmine testing using karma and webpack, and the code is getting transpiled incorrectly, but I can't see what it is transpiled down to because the browser closes as soon as it opens and finds the syntax error. How can I configure karma or jasmine to keep the browser window open after an error occurs?

Comment: --single-run should do the trick for you, or { singleRun: false } in karma.conf.js

Comment: @zxxc when I set singleRun to false, it opens the browser window and doesn't seem to load the tests.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You want to call it with `--single-run=false`.

Try following this article: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/debugging-karma-unit-tests/

Comment: This started working today, but it was not running the tests with this yesterday. Maybe restarting my computer affected the change?

Comment: If the option is not good enough for you: Try using Gulp plus Karma APIs browsers_change event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352256/how-to-keep-browser-window-open-for-single-karma-run-until-i-close-it-once/45375346#45375346

Comment: `Unknown option: '--single-run'`

Comment: for the unknown option error, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816917/angular-cli-6-unknown-option-singlerun

Comment: Use `--watch` instead.

Comment: use --singleRun=false