# Angular CLI 6 Unknown option: '--singleRun'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

When I want to execute my tests, I used to have the option `--single-run` activated, but after upgrading to Angular 6 it is not recognized anymore.

```
> ng test --source-map=false --single-run --no-progress --browsers=ChromeNoSandbox
```

> Unknown option: '--singleRun'

What is the equivalent option in Angular CLI 6 for --single-run ?

Comment: Use ng test --watch
More information here
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10711

Answer (score 67, accepted):

With older versions of angular-cli, you used to be able to use both `--singleRun` and `--watch=false` for the same thing. Now they removed `--singleRun`.

You can still use `ng test --watch=false`

[Angular cli 1.x docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/1-x-test)

> Tests will execute after a build is executed via Karma, and it will automatically watch your files for changes. You can run tests a single time via --watch=false or --single-run.

[Angular cli 6.x docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/test)

> Tests will execute after a build is executed via Karma, and it will automatically watch your files for changes. You can run tests a single time via --watch=false.

Comment: I'd like to point out that for @angular/cli version 7.0.4 this doesn't work.

Comment: To follow on from my previous comment this appears to be an open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12816

Comment: This question is about Angular 6 and not Angular 7.

Answer (score 6):

You should use **[ng test](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10695)**

```
ng test --watch=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this issue and comment

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10711#issuecomment-387704999

Starting from Angular v6, you don't need to specify --single-run